# I need help fixing the error "value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm relatively new to python and all its libraries, and I am a bit confused on what to do with the piece of code I've written in order to get rid of the error
"SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"
My project involves extracting specific data from a CSV file. The file contains diverse housing data for various cities, and my goal is to isolate the data for the city "Whitby" under the "Location" column. Specifically, I aim to calculate the average of the "CompBenchmark" column for rows with the same year in the "Date" column. For instance, if there are multiple rows with the location "Whitby" all having the year 2015 in the "Date" column and different values in the "CompBenchmark" column, I want to average these "CompBenchmark" values that share the year 2015. I intend to repeat this process for the years 2015 to 2021, resulting in a total of seven averaged values for the city of Whitby. How can I achieve this?

This is the code I wrote below. I believe there is a better way of gettig the year in the date column by converting it to datetime in pandas but I wasn't familiar on how to do that, so I just extracted the first 4 characters in the date column because that was the only solution I knew. Feel free to completely change up the method of how I did it as that doesn't matter in my project.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

housing_raw_data_df = pd.read_csv("MLS.csv")
filtered_df = housing_raw_data_df[housing_raw_data_df["Location"] == "Whitby"]
filtered_df.loc[:, "Year"] = filtered_df["Date"].str.slice(0, 4)
average_data = filtered_df.groupby("Year")["CompBenchmark"].mean().reset_index()
print(average_data)
```

Comment: When I do that, I get the same error as above and a key error for the line:

average_data = filtered_df.groupby("Year")["CompBenchmark"].mean().reset_index()

It says the key error is for "Year"

Comment: Use `filtered_df = housing_raw_data_df[housing_raw_data_df["Location"] == "Whitby"].reset_index()`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because you are trying to make changes in filtered_df which is essentially a copy of housing_raw_data_df.

```
filtered_df=housing_raw_data_df.copy(deep=True)
filtered_df = filtered_df.loc[filtered_df["Location"] == "Whitby"]

filtered_df["Year"] = filtered_df["Date"].str.slice(0, 4)
average_data = filtered_df.groupby("Year")["CompBenchmark"].mean().reset_index()
print(average_data)
```

Comment: @user19077881, he needs help fixing "value is trying to be set on cop..." warning and this will definitely help him override the warning by breaking all connections to the parent dataframe.  Even if he uses filtered_df["Year"] = filtered_df["Date"].str.slice(0, 4) (without making a copy), he will still run into same warning.

Comment: You are right. The problem is an indexing issue. A simple solution, not requiring a copy, is just to use `.reset_index()` in the OP statement which produces filtered_df from the housing DF.